# NightwatchJS "freezes"

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Our Nightwatch tests are no longer running when we moved from Windows to Linux. It just freezes.

Selenium server is already listening, and `chrome_driver` (linux 64 bit) setting is correctly set. However, this is what we're getting:

```
$ node nightwatch.js -t tests/mytest.js --verbose

[ mytestmodule ]

Running:  MyTest
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session 
 - data: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":"ANY"},"sessionId":null} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json","Content-Length":129}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Also, can somebody make a tag for NightwatchJS? :)

Comment: I had this output when running a linux version of the chromedriver on windows. Once I downloaded the correct and latest version, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have some problems starting different webdrivers on my mac, if using older versions of selenium jars. Please check if your version of selenium server is up-to-date.

Second idea: try if it runs with Firefox, it seems to be the most-supported browser of selenium now.  If yes, then you can localize the problem to chrome/chrome web driver.

If not, please post your whole setting.json, and perhaps a test-snippet too...